# Как узнать какой ID у пользователя и вывести информацию только по нему и для него?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

Всем здравствуйте. Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться. Сайт на wordpress. Установлены плагины для платного доступа и млм Ultimate Membership Pro и Ultimate Affiliate Pro. Они между собой связаны. Есть такой код (хоть и написан мной и через одно место)

```html
<?php
error_reporting(-1);
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
//Скрипт для 100000
require_once 'connection.php'; // подключаем скрипт
// подключаемся к серверу
  $link = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $password, $database); // Соединяемся с базой
  // Ругаемся, если соединение установить не удалось
  if (!$link) {
    echo 'Не могу соединиться с БД. Код ошибки: ' . mysqli_connect_errno() . ', ошибка: ' . mysqli_connect_error();
    exit;
  }
  $sql = mysqli_query($link, 'SELECT `create_date`,`uid`,`status`,`amount_value`,`lid` FROM `wp_ihc_orders` WHERE `status`= "Completed"');
  while ($result = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) {
     $start=($result['create_date']);
     $user_id=($result['uid']);
     $stat=($result['status']);
     $reg_lid=($result['lid']);
     $amount=($result['amount_value']); 
   /* Время */
     $now = time(); // текущее время (метка времени)
     $datediff = date('d.m.Y') - date("d.m.Y", strtotime($result['create_date'])); // получаем разность дат
if($reg_lid['lid']=1){
  /* Начисляем процент для lid=1*/  
   $proc = 25;
      $proc_d =0.25*$datediff;
   $proc = $amount/100*$proc;
   $proc_d = $amount/100*$proc_d;
   $amountWithPct_all = $amount + $proc;
   $amountWithPct_d = $amount + $proc_d;
   round ($amountWithPct_all);
   round ($amountWithPct_d);   
   }
elseif($reg_lid['lid']=2){
   /* Начисляем процент для lid=2*/
   $proc = 60; //Процентов за всё время
         $proc_d =0.6*$datediff; //Процентов в день
   $proc = $amount/100*$proc; // высчитываем процент от числа
   $proc_d = $amount/200*$proc_d; // высчитываем процент в день от числа
   $amountWithPct_all = $amount + $proc; // суммируем число с процентами от этого числа
   $amountWithPct_d = $amount + $proc_d; // суммируем число с процентами в день от этого числа
   round ($amountWithPct_all); // округляем
   round ($amountWithPct_d); // округляем
}else {
       /* Начисляем процент для lid=3*/
   $proc = 89; //Процентов за всё время
         $proc_d =0.89*$datediff; //Процентов в день
   $proc = $amount/100*$proc; // высчитываем процент от числа
   $proc_d = $amount/300*$proc_d; // высчитываем процент в день от числа
   $amountWithPct_all = $amount + $proc; // суммируем число с процентами от этого числа
   $amountWithPct_d = $amount + $proc_d; // суммируем число с процентами в день от этого числа
   round ($amountWithPct_all); // округляем
   round ($amountWithPct_d); // округляем
}
   /*Выводим результат*/
     echo "Дата начала: {$start}<br>";
    echo "Прошло дней: {$datediff}<br>";
    echo "Внесено: {$amount} ₽<br>";
  echo "Заработано на данный момент: $proc_d ₽<br>";
  echo "Cумма на конец периода: $amountWithPct_all ₽<br><br>";
  }
?>
```

Как узнать какой у залогиненого пользователя ID (uid?) и lid и в соответствии с этими значениями вывести ему информацию? ID (uid?) может быть бесконечное множество, а lid до 15. Что-то не могу разобраться. Я понимаю, что это должно быть не сложно, но я же тупенькая)
Поля таблицы на скрине.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Добавила такую конструкцию: if ( is_user_logged_in()&&($reg_lid['lid']=1)), но всё равно выводится вся информация по всем пользователям. Я так понимаю надо добавить какую-то проверку по ID пользователя и показывать только его данные. Но я совершенно не понимаю как(

Код теперь выглядит так:

```html
<?php
error_reporting(-1);
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
//Скрипт для 100000
require_once 'connection.php'; // подключаем скрипт
// подключаемся к серверу
  $link = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $password, $database); // Соединяемся с базой
  // Ругаемся, если соединение установить не удалось
  if (!$link) {
    echo 'Не могу соединиться с БД. Код ошибки: ' . mysqli_connect_errno() . ', ошибка: ' . mysqli_connect_error();
    exit;
  }
  $sql = mysqli_query($link, 'SELECT `create_date`,`uid`,`status`,`amount_value`,`lid` FROM `wp_ihc_orders` WHERE `status`= "Completed"');
  while ($result = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) {
     $start=($result['create_date']);
     $user_id=($result['uid']);
     $stat=($result['status']);
     $reg_lid=($result['lid']);
     $amount=($result['amount_value']); 
   /* Время */
     $now = time(); // текущее время (метка времени)
     $datediff = date('d.m.Y') - date("d.m.Y", strtotime($result['create_date'])); // получаем разность дат
   
   if ( is_user_logged_in()&&($reg_lid['lid']=1)) {
 echo 'Вы авторизованы на сайте!';
    //if($reg_lid['lid']=1){
  /* Начисляем процент для lid=1*/  
   $proc = 25;
      $proc_d =0.25*$datediff;
   $proc = $amount/100*$proc;
   $proc_d = $amount/100*$proc_d;
   $amountWithPct_all = $amount + $proc;
   $amountWithPct_d = $amount + $proc_d;
   round ($amountWithPct_all);
   round ($amountWithPct_d);   
   }
   elseif(is_user_logged_in()&&($reg_lid['lid']=2)){
//elseif($reg_lid['lid']=2){
   /* Начисляем процент для lid=2*/
   $proc = 60; //Процентов за всё время
         $proc_d =0.6*$datediff; //Процентов в день
   $proc = $amount/100*$proc; // высчитываем процент от числа
   $proc_d = $amount/200*$proc_d; // высчитываем процент в день от числа
   $amountWithPct_all = $amount + $proc; // суммируем число с процентами от этого числа
   $amountWithPct_d = $amount + $proc_d; // суммируем число с процентами в день от этого числа
   round ($amountWithPct_all); // округляем
   round ($amountWithPct_d); // округляем
}
   elseif (is_user_logged_in()&&($reg_lid['lid']=3)){
       /* Начисляем процент для lid=3*/
   $proc = 89; //Процентов за всё время
         $proc_d =0.89*$datediff; //Процентов в день
   $proc = $amount/100*$proc; // высчитываем процент от числа
   $proc_d = $amount/300*$proc_d; // высчитываем процент в день от числа
   $amountWithPct_all = $amount + $proc; // суммируем число с процентами от этого числа
   $amountWithPct_d = $amount + $proc_d; // суммируем число с процентами в день от этого числа
   round ($amountWithPct_all); // округляем
   round ($amountWithPct_d); // округляем
}
   else{
    echo "Данных ещё нет";
   }
   /*Выводим результат*/
     echo "Дата начала: {$start}<br>";
    echo "Прошло дней: {$datediff}<br>";
    echo "Внесено: {$amount} ₽<br>";
  echo "Заработано на данный момент: $proc_d ₽<br>";
  echo "Cумма на конец периода: $amountWithPct_all ₽<br><br>";
  }
   

?>
```

Comment: вначале is_user_logged_in, затем (если действительно понадобится) get_users, get_userdata и тп

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Разобралась. Надо было в условии вывода задать сравнение ID и uid из разных таблиц. Код получился большим и грязным но, вдруг кому-то это поможет. 
Сам код:

```html
<?php
error_reporting(-1);
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
//Скрипт для 100000
require_once 'connection.php'; // подключаем скрипт
// подключаемся к серверу
  $link = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $password, $database); // Соединяемся с базой
  // Ругаемся, если соединение установить не удалось
  if (!$link) {
    echo 'Не могу соединиться с БД. Код ошибки: ' . mysqli_connect_errno() . ', ошибка: ' . mysqli_connect_error();
    exit;
  }
 global $wpdb;
 $cur_user = wp_get_current_user()->user_login;
 $cur_id = get_current_user_id();
  $sql = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT " . $wpdb->base_prefix . "ihc_orders.create_date, " . $wpdb->base_prefix . "ihc_orders.uid, " . $wpdb->base_prefix . "ihc_orders.status , " . $wpdb->base_prefix . "ihc_orders.amount_value, " . $wpdb->base_prefix . "ihc_orders.lid, " . $wpdb->base_prefix . "users.id FROM " . $wpdb->base_prefix . "ihc_orders, " . $wpdb->base_prefix . "users WHERE " . $wpdb->base_prefix . "ihc_orders.uid=" . $wpdb->base_prefix . "users.id AND status= 'Completed'");
  while ($result = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) {
     $start=($result['create_date']);
     $user_uid=($result['uid']);
     $user_id=($result['id']);
   $usid=($user_uid===$user_id);
     $stat=($result['status']);
     $reg_lid=($result['lid']);
     $amount=($result['amount_value']); 
  /* Время */
     $now = time(); // текущее время (метка времени)
     $datediff = date('d.m.Y') - date("d.m.Y", strtotime($result['create_date'])); // получаем разность дат
      
   if ( is_user_logged_in()&&$user_uid==$cur_id&&($reg_lid['lid']=1)) {
 echo 'Вы авторизованы на сайте!<br>';
  /* Начисляем процент для lid=1*/  
   $proc = 25;
      $proc_d =0.25*$datediff;
   $proc = $amount/100*$proc;
   $proc_d = $amount/100*$proc_d;
   $amountWithPct_all = $amount + $proc;
   $amountWithPct_d = $amount + $proc_d;
   round ($amountWithPct_all);
   round ($amountWithPct_d);
    
    
    if ($user_uid==$cur_id) {
        /*Выводим результат*/
  echo "ID пользователя: {$user_uid}<br>";
    echo "ID пользователя из get: {$cur_id}<br>";
     echo "Дата начала: {$start}<br>";
    echo "Прошло дней: {$datediff}<br>";
    echo "Внесено: {$amount} ₽<br>";
  echo "Заработано на данный момент: $proc_d ₽<br>";
  echo "Cумма на конец периода: $amountWithPct_all ₽<br><br>";
} else {
    echo 'Нет данных';
}

   }
   elseif(is_user_logged_in()&&$user_uid==$cur_id&&($reg_lid['lid']=2)){
   /* Начисляем процент для lid=2*/
   $proc = 60; //Процентов за всё время
         $proc_d =0.6*$datediff; //Процентов в день
   $proc = $amount/100*$proc; // высчитываем процент от числа
   $proc_d = $amount/200*$proc_d; // высчитываем процент в день от числа
   $amountWithPct_all = $amount + $proc; // суммируем число с процентами от этого числа
   $amountWithPct_d = $amount + $proc_d; // суммируем число с процентами в день от этого числа
   round ($amountWithPct_all); // округляем
   round ($amountWithPct_d); // округляем
    
        if ($user_uid==$cur_id) {
  /*Выводим результат*/  
  echo "ID пользователя: {$user_uid}<br>";
    echo "ID пользователя из get: {$cur_id}<br>";
     echo "Дата начала: {$start}<br>";
    echo "Прошло дней: {$datediff}<br>";
    echo "Внесено: {$amount} ₽<br>";
  echo "Заработано на данный момент: $proc_d ₽<br>";
  echo "Cумма на конец периода: $amountWithPct_all ₽<br><br>";
} else {
    echo 'Нет данных';
}    
}
   elseif (is_user_logged_in()&&$user_uid==$cur_id&&($reg_lid['lid']=3)){
       /* Начисляем процент для lid=3*/
   $proc = 89; //Процентов за всё время
         $proc_d =0.89*$datediff; //Процентов в день
   $proc = $amount/100*$proc; // высчитываем процент от числа
   $proc_d = $amount/300*$proc_d; // высчитываем процент в день от числа
   $amountWithPct_all = $amount + $proc; // суммируем число с процентами от этого числа
   $amountWithPct_d = $amount + $proc_d; // суммируем число с процентами в день от этого числа
   round ($amountWithPct_all); // округляем
   round ($amountWithPct_d); // округляем
    
            if ($user_uid==$cur_id) {
   /*Выводим результат*/ 
  echo "ID пользователя: {$user_uid}<br>";
    echo "ID пользователя из get: {$cur_id}<br>";
     echo "Дата начала: {$start}<br>";
    echo "Прошло дней: {$datediff}<br>";
    echo "Внесено: {$amount} ₽<br>";
  echo "Заработано на данный момент: $proc_d ₽<br>";
  echo "Cумма на конец периода: $amountWithPct_all ₽<br><br>";
} else {
    echo 'Нет данных';
}

}
   else{
   }   
  } 
?>
```